# CodeChecker Warning: file contents changed or missing since the latest analysis

Tags: database, upload, report, warnings, static-analysis

I executed locally a static analysis using Codechecker.

Now I want to store the results (generated in the `reports` folder) in CodeChecker database using the command

```
CodeChecker store ./reports --name my_first_run --url http://<codechecker_ip>:8555/Default
```

as documented in [Store analysis results in a CodeChecker DB](https://imrenagy.gitbooks.io/codechecker/content/usage.html).

but page is empty like in the image below

[image]

Am I missing  something?
Do I need to updload source code?

After the command, from log I see this warning

```
[INFO 2023-09-25 07:11] - Processing report files done.
[WARNING 2023-09-25 07:11] - The following source file contents changed or missing since the latest analysis:
 - /home/runner/work/codechecker-analysis-action-test/codechecker-analysis-action-test/src/main.cpp
Please re-analyze your project to update the reports!
```

I would expect to be able to view the results in my web browser http://<codechecker_ip>:8555/Default as in the following image
[image]